# Is Alfresco 4.2.x compatible with Alfresco SDK 3.0.0-beta-4?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

I am trying to build a module for Alfresco Share 4.2.2.

According to [compatibility matrix](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/alfresco-sdk-compatibility.html) Alfresco 4.2.x is only compatible with Maven SDK 1.1.x. However, when I create an amp executing

`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/archetype-catalog.xml -Dfilter=org.alfresco.maven.archetype:`

which is indicated [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/dev-extensions-maven-sdk-tutorials-amp-archetype.html), without asking the SDK version, the amp is built with the version 3.0.0-beta-4.

What is happening? Is there any problem building an amp with 3.0.0-beta-4 for Alfresco 4.2.2? If not, how can I find sdk 1.1.x?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for Alfresco Maven SDK 1.1.0 you can find it [here](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/alfresco-docs/alfresco-lifecycle-aggregator/latest/index.html)

As you can see in this [Alfresco Developer Blog post](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2016/08/23/alfresco-sdk-3-beta-1-available/), looking at ***What's new*** section, it seems that since Alfresco SDK 3 beta 1 there is

> Support for 4.2 (currently Share module requires you to add two
>   dependencies by hand)

You can also get way more info looking at Alfresco's [alfresco-sdk project on Github](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a project for alfresco 4.2 with the SDK 3.
The documentation is in the alfresco 5.2 ducumentation, in the paragraph of the SDK:
[Alfresco SDK 3.0 | Alfresco Documentation](https://community.alfresco.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.alfresco.com%2Fcommunity%2Fconcepts%2Fsdk-intro.html)
and more precisely here:
[Switch to using Alfresco version 4.2.x | Alfresco Documentation](https://community.alfresco.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.alfresco.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftasks%2Fsdk-using-42.html)